# time function in C

Tags: c, datetime, time

In shell scripting, when ever I want the local time I do something like

```
date +%s
```

from the command line and it returns me the current date and time in this format "1343221713"

I am wondering whether there is a way to achieve the same result in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More flexible than `time(3)` is `gettimeofday(3)` as declared in `sys/time.h`

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        struct timeval tv = {0};
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        printf("seconds since epoch %ld, microseconds %ld\n", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use time.h library in C

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    /* Obtain current time as seconds elapsed since the Epoch. */
    time_t clock = time(NULL);

    /* Convert to local time format and print to stdout. */
    printf("Current time is %s", ctime(&clock));
    return 0;
}
```

see more examples:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions